# How can I use node-orm2 to model two or more databases with Express?

Tags: database, node.js, orm

I'm trying to use [node-orm2](https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2) as middleware with [Express](http://expressjs.com/) the documentation only shows how you can connect to one database only.

I have tried getting Express to use two different middleware layers, but no luck. For instance,

```
app.use(orm.express('sqlite://test.db', define: { /* define table1 */ }));
app.use(orm.express('sqlite://test2.db', define: { /* define table2 */ }));
```

I've routed everything correctly to this `get` handler:

```
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
   var t1 = req.db.models.table1.find(...);
   var t2 = req.db.models.table2.find(...);
   res.send([t1,t2]);
});
```

Since I `app.use`d  `table1`'s database first, the second of the `find` invocations will yield

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'find' of undefined
```

... which means that the two `define:` blocks haven't been merged, which is what we'd like.

How would I access two databases with node-orm2?

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems fine. I think the problem is that you're using "req.db.models" instead of just "req.models". From the [documentation](https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2):

```
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    // req.models is a reference to models used above in define()
    req.models.person.find(...);
});
```

And also:

> You can call orm.express more than once to have multiple database connections. Models defined across connections will be joined together in **req.models**. Don't forget to use it before app.use(app.router), preferably right after your assets public folder(s).

Everything just gets mushed together under "models," there's no differentiator between databases. This means you can't name your models the same thing across multiple DBs, but c'est la guerre.